# How to choose from a set of constraints? Generalization of either or constrains?

Tags: integer-programming

In an either or constraint, we have two constraints and we have to choose only one. For example if we have

```
constraint_1 <= value_1
```

or

```
constraint_2 <= value_2
```

We can introduce a binary variable `y = 0` or `1` and write

```
constraint_1 <= value_1 + M * y
```

and

```
constraint_2 <= value_2 + M * (1 - y)
```

for a sufficiently large `M`.

How about if we have a set of constraints and we have to choose one of them?

```
constraint_t <= value_t for t = 1,...,T
```

and only one of the `T` constraints must be true. Can we model this using integer linear programming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this can be done as follows. Introduce `T` binary variables `z_t` and write:

```
constraint_t <= value_t + M * z_t
z_1 + z_2 + ... + z_T = T - 1
```